# Two questions on biblatex: remove parentheses on urldate, and change "url" label

Tags: biblatex, urls

I have a couple of questions on biblatex.

**First:**
When I use the `urldate` field in a biblatex entry, I get as a result the following string (e.g.):

```
. . . (visited on 01/02/2012).
```

With `\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}` I can change the label `visited on`, but cannot change the fact that the resulting string is included within parentheses. Is there a way to remove them?

**Second:**
When typesetting biblatex entries that contain URLs, the result (in `authoryear-comp`, at least) always prints in small caps the label "url:". Is there a way to change it to something like "Available at"? I tried unsuccessfully the following:

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  url = {Available at}
  }
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{available}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  available = {available at},
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\bibstring{available}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\addcomma\space\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
  url = {tex.stackexchange.com},
  urldate = {2012-04-08},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `available` in `DefineBibliographyStrings` shall be replaced with `url` otherwise it results in an error.

Answer (score 11):

All formats of biblatex defined in the file `biblatex.def` which is part of the documentation.

**First:**

The default format of the field urldate is:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}}
```

To remove the parentheses use:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\bibstring{urlseen}\space#1}
```

**Second:**

Works like the first method.

The default of `biblatex.def` is:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\url{#1}}
```

whereby `\mkbibacro` prints acronyms in small caps if possible.
So there is no bibliography string `url`. You can define one and uses as usual.

Comment: Great, thanks! What if I wanted to remove the space before "Retrieved:" (e.g., if wanted ", retrieved ")? I tried the following solution: `\DeclareFieldFormat{urldate}{\hspace{-1ex}, retrieved\space#1}`, but there must be a more elegant one, I assume.