# Invoking biblatex macro for "(visited on <date>)"

Tags: biblatex, urls

Can I invoke some biblatex commands or macros in order to automatically generate a string like this:

```
(visited on 04/01/2013)
```

I have this outside of a `\cite` command in a footnote, but would like to automatically get the same text and formatting as biblatex would use when printing this information. So something like

```
\printurlseen{2013-01-04}  % hypothetical code
```

Comment: would the entry be part of your bib file? if it is you could use the `\fnotecite{<key>}` which would put the full reference as a footnote and not in the bibliography section. Is that what you are after?

Comment: @ArTourter - I could add it to the bib file, no problem. But I really just want to print the url and the urlseen part, nothing else (no authors, year, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biblatex has `\citeurl{citekey}`. However, this does not output the information about when the url has been visited.

A possible way to modify it is

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeurl}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\printfield[citeurl]{url}
    \iffieldundef{urlyear}
      {}
      {\printurldate}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Comment: Thank you. With the help [of this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51194/two-questions-on-biblatex-remove-parentheses-on-urldate-and-change-url-label#51198) I modified the third last line in your example to `{\mkbibparens{\bibstring{urlseen}\space\printurldate}}` -- this does now exactly what I want.